# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with my React application. First, of all, it runs fine after typing **yarn start**. However, I disconnect on purpose from my local json-server to see what error is generated. It is expected to see something like this.

[image: Expected response]

Instead, I see this in the browser's console.

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'image' of undefined
RenderCard
src/components/HomeComponent.js:28
  25 | return(
  26 |     <Card>
  27 |         <CardBody>
> 28 |         <CardImg src={baseUrl + item.image} alt={item.name} />
     | ^  29 |             <CardTitle>{item.name}</CardTitle>
  30 |             {item.designation ? <CardSubtitle>{item.designation}</CardSubtitle>: null}
  31 |             <CardText>{item.description}</CardText>
View compiled
▶ 23 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/redux/ActionCreators.js:31
  28 |     error => {
  29 |         var errorMessage = new Error(error.errorMessage);
  30 |         throw errorMessage;
> 31 |     }
     | ^  32 | )
  33 | .then(response => response.json())
  34 | .then(dishes => dispatch(addDishes(dishes)))
```

Here is how I define the actions that are sent on the reducers.

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';

export const addComment = (dishId, rating, author, comment) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT,
    payload: {
        dishId: dishId,
        rating: rating,
        author: author,
        comment: comment
    }
});

export const fetchDishes = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(dishesLoading(true));

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'dishes')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            } else {
                var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        },
            error => {
                var errorMessage = new Error(error.errorMessage);
                throw errorMessage;
            }
        )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(dishes => dispatch(addDishes(dishes)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(dishesFailed(error.message)))
}

export const dishesLoading = () => (dispatch) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.DISHES_LOADING
});

export const dishesFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.DISHES_FAILED,
    payload: errmess
});

export const addDishes = (dishes) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_DISHES,
    payload: dishes
});

export const fetchComments = () => (dispatch) => {
    return fetch(baseUrl + 'comments')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            } else {
                var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;

                throw error;
            }
        },
            error => {
                var errorMessage = new Error(error.errorMessage);
                throw errorMessage;
            }
        )

        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(comments => dispatch(addComments(comments)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(commentsFailed(error.message)))
}

export const commentsFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.COMMENTS_FAILED,
    payload: errmess
});

export const addComments = (comments) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENTS,
    payload: comments
});

export const fetchPromos = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(promosLoading(true));

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'promotions')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            } else {
                var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;

                throw error;
            }
        },
            error => {
                var errorMessage = new Error(error.errorMessage);
                throw errorMessage;
            }
        )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(promos => dispatch(addPromos(promos)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(promosFailed(error.message)))
}

export const promosLoading = () => (dispatch) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.PROMOS_LOADING
});

export const promosFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.PROMOS_FAILED,
    payload: errmess
});

export const addPromos = (promos) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_PROMOS,
    payload: promos
});
```

And my HomeComponent

```
function RenderCard({item,isLoading,errMess}){ 
    if (isLoading){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <Loading />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    if(errMess){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <h4>{errMess}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    } else
        return(
            <Card>
                <CardBody>
                <CardImg src={baseUrl + item.image} alt={item.name} />
                    <CardTitle>{item.name}</CardTitle>
                    {item.designation ? <CardSubtitle>{item.designation}</CardSubtitle>: null}
                    <CardText>{item.description}</CardText>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        );
}

function Home(props){
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row align-items-start">
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-4 m-1">
                        <RenderCard item={props.dish} 
                            isLoading={props.dishesLoading} 
                            errMess={props.dishesErrMess} 
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
                    <RenderCard item={props.promotion} isLoading={props.promoLoading} errMess={props.promoErrMess} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
                        <RenderCard item={props.leader} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

This is my project

https://github.com/theo82/Front-End-Web-Development-With-React

How can I fix that error?
Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: If the props you are passing Home function dont have any innitial value, till its received from the request, its pretty normal to get error.

Also even though you have initial value, you always can precheck if value exist or not for example:
{item.image?<component></component>:null }

Comment: Hello Ibrahim. I have a link of my project if you want to have a look

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you are filtering the leaders and passing first index in MainComponent.js line 53, which may always be undefined. You should check if that value exists or not.

to do that replace the HomeComponent.js line 25 with below code:

```
 return (item?<Card>
                <CardBody>
                <CardImg src={baseUrl + item.image} alt={item.name} />
                    <CardTitle>{item.name}</CardTitle>
                    {item.designation ? <CardSubtitle>{item.designation}</CardSubtitle>: null}
                    <CardText>{item.description}</CardText>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>:null)
```

Also you could render a placeholder component instead of null value I wrote. Thats up to you.

Comment: The item value null. That's interesting

Answer (score 1):

correct props for `errMess` in `RenderCard` component( in Home component) is `props.dishErrMess` not `props.dishesErrMess`.
actuly in MainComponent `<Home dishErrMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}/>`

Answer (score 0):

This belongs to Full Stack development with React Course at Coursera.

- Start the MongoDB server.
- Then start the REST API Server that you have implemented in Server-side Development
  with NodeJS, Express and MongoDB.
- Then start [ConFusion-React](https://github.com/jmuppala/conFusion-React) (Must
  contains all the related node modules) by npm start or yarn start.

**If this error continues then do the following changes:**

- Start your REST API Server and MongoDB Server
- Open Postman and login as `admin`
- Then use `db.json` file that you have downloaded from resources and insert all the
  dishes, leaders, promotions and users at respective endpoints and also check it at
  MongoDB shell by using different commands.
- Then do all the initial process that I have discussed above.

*Do Upvote If this resolves your problem else comment.*